# Custom FrameTicks not working

Tags: plotting, ticks

I would like to have a custom ticks on x-axis on my `ListPlot`, but nothing is showing, what am I doing wrong?

```
data = {{1, 2}, {2, -2}, {3, -1}, {4, 0}, {5, -3},
 {6, -2}, {7, -1}, {8, -1}, {9, -1}, {10, 0}};

ListPlot[data, 
 FrameTicks -> {{"ττ", "τr", "τθ", 
    "\τφ", "rr", "rθ", "rφ", 
    "θθ", "θφ", 
    "φφ"}, {-5, 5}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, Axes -> False,ImageSize -> 500]
```

And I get

[image]

Comment: Why do you think this will work. Have you looked at `FrameTicks` and `Ticks` documentation? Especially Details section is going to be helpful.

Comment: So I cannot put any custom ticks in Mathematica? Well that sucks :(

Comment: @dingo_d Of course you can; Kuba is saying that you don't have the correct syntax.  Please see the answer to the question I just closed this as a duplicate of.  Also re-read the documentation for Ticks and FrameTicks.

Comment: I had an answer with you that solved this particular problem but the duplicate will do just as well. Here's a start: `labels = {"\[Tau]\[Tau]", "\[Tau]r", "\[Tau]\[Theta]", 
   "\[Tau]\[CurlyPhi]", "rr", "r\[Theta]", "r\[CurlyPhi]", 
   "\[Theta]\[Theta]", "\[Theta]\[CurlyPhi]", 
   "\[CurlyPhi]\[CurlyPhi]"}; ticks = Table[x, {x, 0, 9}]; frameticks = Transpose[{ticks, labels}]` then set the option `FrameTicks -> {{False, False}, {frameticks, False}}`

Comment: Oh, it can :D Thanks. I read Details section, but found nothing that could help :\

Comment: data = {{1, 2}, {2, -2}, {3, -1}, {4, 
        0}, {5, -3}, {6, -2}, {7, -1}, {8, -1}, {9, -1}, {10, 0}};
    
    ListPlot[data,
     FrameTicks -> {{Range[-3, 2], Range[-3, 2]},
                    {Partition[Riffle[Range@10, {"ττ", "τr", "τθ", "τφ", "rr", "rθ", "rφ", "θθ", "θφ", "φφ"}], 2], None}}, Frame -> True, 
            PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 500]

Comment: @dingo_d In `FramTicks` details: `"For each edge, tick marks can be specified as described in the notes for Ticks."`. And as it is written, in `Ticks` documentation there are examples how the proper syntax with labels looks.

Comment: Sorry, didn't look carefully :\